# sql server if statement not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, sql-update

Can anyone advise me as to what is wrong with the following SQL server `update` statement:

```
IF (SELECT * FROM TBL_SystemParameter WHERE code='SOUND_WRONG_GARMENT') = ''
GO
UPDATE TBL_SystemParameter 
SET [Value] = 'Ping.wav' 
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID 
            FROM TBL_SystemParameter 
            WHERE code = 'SOUND_WRONG_GARMENT')
```

Comment: shouldn't you select just a single column instead of everything (`*`)

Comment: Can you have multiple ID's with the same code?  In that case it should be `IN (Select...)` if not just do `WHERE code = 'SOUND_WRONG_GARMENT'`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an `if` statement - you can just run the update statement, and if the subquery returns no rows, no rows will be updated. The `if` won't really save anything - you're performing two queries instead of one.

Comment: And if you ever do need an if statement for something like this, I find that using an exists statement often cleaner than comparing the result of a select statement to a value.

Answer (score 2):

Although Mureinik's answer is the logical solution to this, I will answer why this isn't actually working. Your condition is wrong, and this approach will work instead using `IF EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TBL_SystemParameter WHERE code='SOUND_WRONG_GARMENT')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TBL_SystemParameter 
        SET [Value] = 'Ping.wav' 
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID 
            FROM TBL_SystemParameter 
            WHERE code = 'SOUND_WRONG_GARMENT')
    END
```

As a side note, you're using an `=` sign instead of `IN`, which means you'll be matching to an arbitrary singular ID and only update 1 row based on this. To use a set based operation, use the `IN` clause.

You could actually 'golf' this by doing away with the derived query altogether, and using a simple `WHERE code='SOUND_WRONG_GARMENT'` on the table you're updating on.

Comment: Except checking for the value is completely superfluous; if you run the `update` statement, it will either update or it won't; no need to check for the record's existence before updating it.  Additionally, it should be `WHERE ID IN`, in case the subquery returns more than one result.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, you didn't read my answer properly did you?

Comment: well, when I commented, your last two paragraphs weren't there, and your SQL statement still had `=` instead of `IN`.  Since you keep editing your answer, no need to be snippy about it.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables, no snippyness here. I did pre-text my answer with acknowledging that a simple `UPDATE` is the correct solution though. I was simply pointing out why his code wasn't playing out the expected logical flow, there's more to this question than the way he *should* be doing it, he can learn about `IF` at the same time, resulting in two lessons in one :)

Answer (score 2):

You either want

```
UPDATE TBL_SystemParameter 
SET [Value] = 'Ping.wav' 
WHERE ID In (SELECT ID 
        FROM TBL_SystemParameter 
        WHERE code = 'SOUND_WRONG_GARMENT')
```

if there are multiple ID's with that code OR use

```
UPDATE TBL_SystemParameter 
SET [Value] = 'Ping.wav' 
WHERE code = 'SOUND_WRONG_GARMENT'
```

either way and lose the IF statement as @Mureinik said.